There are several things I don't understand in this sentence
내가 초등학생이었을때부터 7년을 알고 지내왔기에 나에게는 거의 친누나나 다름이 없었다.
Keep in mind I only recently started learning Korean (approximately 1 week) before deciding to learn by reading web novels.

7년을 알고
I feel as if 동안 should've been used here

지내왔기에
I have never seen 지내오다 and I can't find it in a dictionary. I also hardly understand the use of 기에 here.

친누나나
I don't know why 나 is used here and from what examples I have seen it doesn't seem to make much sense to me.


Only thing I can gleam from this is that the protagonist is comparing his older sister to another older girl and is saying there was no difference between them.


내가 초등학생이었을때부터 7년을 알고 지내왔기에 나에게는 거의 친누나나 다름이 없었다.
As I had known her for seven years since when I was in grade school, she was almost no different from a real sister.

So it is not comparing her to someone else but just saying she was practically like a sister to the speaker.

알고 지내왔기에 = 알고 지내왔(다) + -기에 (because/since ...).
알고 지내왔다 = 알고 지내(다) + -어 왔다 (have been doing ...).
알고 지내다 = to maintain acquaintance / to be on speaking terms with someone.
알고 지내다 should be treated as a unit of expression.  알다 (know someone) + -고 (connector)  + 지내다 (live; pass time).

7년을 알고 지내다 is a simpler way to say 7년 동안을 알고 지내다.  You can put the objective case particle 을/를 after a span of time or distance (사흘을 굶었다 = starved for three days; 300키로를 여행했다 = traveled three hundred kilometers).

친누나나 다름이 없었다 = 친누나와 다름이 없었다 = (she) was no different from a blood sister.
N-와/과 다름이 없다 = N-와 다르지 않다 = is not different from N.  (다름 = difference, 없다 = there is none).
N-와/과/하고 다름이 없다 is the more common form, but you can also say N-나 다름이 없다 / 같다 to emphasize the similarity (especially in informal conversation since 나 sounds casual compared with the more formal 와/과).


It's a compound sentence with some idiomatic phrases, so it's not going to be easy for a new learner to parse it just by looking up the dictionary.
Feel free to ask if you have further questions on specific parts of it.

You my good friend have saved me a bunch of time and an immense headache from trying read this web novel. The only other question I could possibly have is where can I find a resource that provides information about idiomatic phrases. Since I'm dealing with literature, I don't believe howtostudykorean.com is going to cut it as a reference on it's own.

You're more than welcome.  For an additional resource, I would recommend http://www.koreangrammaticalforms.com.  It lists pretty comprehensive phrasal expressions that might not be listed in dictionaries (since dictionaries only list the unit words and expressions).  Although the explanations don't go very deep, it cites very good examples compiled from well known literary works.
